# TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-context

I am making a To-do app using the Context API in React. On starting the deveopment server, it throws the error :

**TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function**
[image]

I am a beginner in React and cannot find out any possible reason for this problem to occur. Here is my `App.js` :

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import Container from "reactstrap/lib/Container";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css';

import {TodoContext} from './Context/TodoContext';
import todoReducer from "./Context/reducer";

const App = () => {
  const [todo, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, [])
  return(
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{todo, dispatch}}>
      <Container fluid>
        <h1>
          Todo App with Context API
        </h1>
      </Container>
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I am using `^16.3.1` for both `react` and `react-dom`

Comment: `import {createContext} from 'react'`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your `TodoContext.js` you incorrectly imported `createContext`. Instead of

```
import createContext from 'react';
```

you should use

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 6):

Import `createContext` with brackets so React knows you're taking the function instead of the whole thing. That way you can actually export the function out. This is where the error in your code popped up. If you didn't, then React would not think that `createContext` was a function.

Answer (score 0):

export {default} from './InsuranceCreate';          the correct answer

the one that causes bugs
import InsuranceCreat from './InsuranceCreate';
export default InsuranceCreate;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).